# Unable to resolve TCDL tags: Sites 9 CIL

Tags: sites-9, cil, tcdl

We are upgrading web 8.1 to Sites 9 and at the application end, we were using in-process API. Now I'm trying to set up using CIL for sites 9. Though other things are working fine with CIL, TCDL tags with an expression like `device.mobile="false"` not getting resolved. During in-process set up we used tag bundle `contextTagRendererBundle.xml` and mentioned this cd_dynamic file. From [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-448BF762-47F1-45BA-AF44-93E19C8E6645&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-448BF762-47F1-45BA-AF44-93E19C8E6645.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-448BF762-47F1-45BA-AF44-93E19C8E6645&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dtcdl&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1576725532215&currentQuery=tcdl&currentScope=) I can see that I need to add the same bundle reference at the cd_dynamic file of the session enabled content service (we are using session content service).

If I follow the document and add the tag bundle `contextTagRendererBundle.xml` in the cd_dynamic file, then session content service is getting stopped with an error saying unable to configure the tag bundle.

> 2019-12-18 23:09:28,010 ERROR [Sessions cleaner thread] StorageConfigurationTransformer - Could not load storage configuration
>   com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Could not read storage configuration file cd_storage_conf.xml
>                   at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageConfigurationTransformer.doTransformConfiguration(StorageConfigurationTransformer.java:76)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageConfigurationTransformer.transformConfiguration(StorageConfigurationTransformer.java:58)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageResourceConfigurationLoaderImpl.init(StorageResourceConfigurationLoaderImpl.java:25)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1623)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>                   at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.SpringContentDeliveryKernel.ensureInitialised(SpringContentDeliveryKernel.java:38)
>                   at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.registerKernel(KernelFactory.java:40)
>                   at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.getKernel(KernelFactory.java:27)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getComponent(StorageManagerFactory.java:76)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getStorageManager(StorageManagerFactory.java:55)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAOForStorageId(StorageManagerFactory.java:260)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionServiceImpl.getRightDAO(SessionServiceImpl.java:476)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionServiceImpl.getNextExpirationDate(SessionServiceImpl.java:347)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.calculateNextExpirationTimeOut(SessionManagerImpl.java:400)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.performCleanup(SessionManagerImpl.java:191)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManager.performCleanup(SessionManager.java:58)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManager.performCleanup(SessionManager.java:54)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionsCleanerMonitor.run(SessionsCleanerMonitor.java:51)
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException: null
>                   at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(Unknown Source)
>                   at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.size(Unknown Source)
>                   at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Unknown Source)
>                   at com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageConfigurationTransformer.doTransformConfiguration(StorageConfigurationTransformer.java:74)
>                   ... 49 common frames omitted
>   2019-12-18 23:09:30,573 ERROR [main] SpringApplication - Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamicContentProcessor' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/SDL/Tridion/session/services/content-service/udp-content-model-11.0.0-1035.jar!/com/sdl/delivery/content/model/core/dynamic/DynamicContentProcessor.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.sdl.delivery.content.model.core.dynamic.DynamicContentProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1104)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>                   at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>                   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>                   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>                   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.service.ServiceContainer.main(ServiceContainer.java:91)
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.start(WinServiceContainer.java:24)
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.main(WinServiceContainer.java:41)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.sdl.delivery.content.model.core.dynamic.DynamicContentProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                   at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1152)
>                   ... 21 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.content.model.core.dynamic.DynamicContentProcessor.(DynamicContentProcessor.java:42)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
>                   ... 23 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ConfigurationException; Could not configure tagsProcessor
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.configure(TCDLProcessor.java:70)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.(TCDLProcessor.java:42)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.loadInstance(TCDLProcessor.java:87)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.(TCDLProcessor.java:27)
>                   ... 29 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to register handler
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TagHandlerRegistry.configure(TagHandlerRegistry.java:391)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLEngine.configureTagHandlers(TCDLEngine.java:222)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLEngine.configure(TCDLEngine.java:118)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.configure(TCDLProcessor.java:101)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.configure(TCDLProcessor.java:66)
>                   ... 32 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.tridion.transformer.TCDLTransformerException: Unable to create TagHandler instance. Class: com.sdl.context.renderer.IfTagRenderer
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TagHandlerRegistry$TagRegistryEntry.newInstance(TagHandlerRegistry.java:116)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TagHandlerRegistry.registerHandler(TagHandlerRegistry.java:339)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TagHandlerRegistry.configure(TagHandlerRegistry.java:389)
>                   ... 36 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sdl.context.renderer.IfTagRenderer
>                   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:45)
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:31)
>                   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TagHandlerRegistry$TagRegistryEntry.newInstance(TagHandlerRegistry.java:109)
>                   ... 38 common frames omitted
>   2019-12-18 23:09:30,573 ERROR [main] ServiceContainer - Could not start ServiceContainer
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.service.ServiceContainer.main(ServiceContainer.java:91)
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.start(WinServiceContainer.java:24)
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.main(WinServiceContainer.java:41)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamicContentProcessor' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/SDL/Tridion/session/services/content-service/udp-content-model-11.0.0-1035.jar!/com/sdl/delivery/content/model/core/dynamic/DynamicContentProcessor.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.sdl.delivery.content.model.core.dynamic.DynamicContentProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1104)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>                   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>                   at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>                   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>                   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>                   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>                   ... 7 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.sdl.delivery.content.model.core.dynamic.DynamicContentProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                   at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1152)
>                   ... 21 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.content.model.core.dynamic.DynamicContentProcessor.(DynamicContentProcessor.java:42)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
>                   ... 23 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ConfigurationException; Could not configure tagsProcessor
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.configure(TCDLProcessor.java:70)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.(TCDLProcessor.java:42)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.loadInstance(TCDLProcessor.java:87)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.(TCDLProcessor.java:27)
>                   ... 29 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to register handler
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TagHandlerRegistry.configure(TagHandlerRegistry.java:391)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLEngine.configureTagHandlers(TCDLEngine.java:222)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLEngine.configure(TCDLEngine.java:118)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.configure(TCDLProcessor.java:101)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLProcessor.configure(TCDLProcessor.java:66)
>                   ... 32 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.tridion.transformer.TCDLTransformerException: Unable to create TagHandler instance. Class: com.sdl.context.renderer.IfTagRenderer
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TagHandlerRegistry$TagRegistryEntry.newInstance(TagHandlerRegistry.java:116)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TagHandlerRegistry.registerHandler(TagHandlerRegistry.java:339)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TagHandlerRegistry.configure(TagHandlerRegistry.java:389)
>                   ... 36 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sdl.context.renderer.IfTagRenderer
>                   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:45)
>                   at com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:31)
>                   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>                   at com.tridion.tcdl.TagHandlerRegistry$TagRegistryEntry.newInstance(TagHandlerRegistry.java:109)
>                   ... 38 common frames omitted

Do I need any additional set up to resolve the TCDL with context expressions?